# Can't receive notification with Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having an issue with Firebase Cloud Messaging (I'm trying to use it in the web) in which I get the Token and when i use it to send a notification , it give me a good response like this:

```
{"multicast_id":5064947793483036169,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1496136155591444%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

but i don't receive the notification.

This is the script that should receive the notification:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase-app.js">
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.0.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<script>
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaS.........7AP0",
    authDomain: "prova-notifications.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://prova-notifications.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "prova-notifications",
    storageBucket: "prova-notifications.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "59.......20"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.requestPermission()
.then(function() {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    return messaging.getToken();
})
.then(function(token) {
    console.log(token);
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
});

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log("Message received. ", payload);
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here a sample payload that i'm sending:

```
Host: fcm.googleapis.com
Authorization: key=AAAAilrlPU.........LBA90EJk
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "body": "5 to 1"
  },
  "to": "eHdpi3OX..........5AvG"
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrea1234567. Could you post a sample payload that you're sending?

Comment: I edited with it

Comment: Thanks! Code and payload looks fine to me.. Maybe something with your network connection? Are you using a personal connection or a work/school connection?

Comment: personal connection